# Insert values from a drop down list to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert values from a drop down list to my database table
it's actually register but shows only two letters as you can see in the picture.

[image]

```
<form method="post" action="#" role="login" id="formID" >
    <select name="states" id="state" required class="form-control input-lg">
        <option value="" selected="selected">select an option</option>
        <option value="AL">ADRAR</option>
        <option value="AK">AIN DEFLA  </option>
    </select>
</form>


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "me";

mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($db_name);

$uwilaya = $_POST ['states'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO userz (wilaya) VALUES ('$uwilaya')";

if($_POST['submit']) {
    $query = mysql_query($sql); 
}
```

Comment: Code poorly formatted ;)

Comment: the question's unclear; there's code missing

Comment: *"but shows only two letters"* - That's what you told it to insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'value' attribute of the option is what is submitted to PHP. If you want the whole word you should put that as your value!

Comment: Also you have an SQL injection vulnerability, make sure you at least escape the $_POST and read up on prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="#" role="login" id="formID" >
    <select name="states" id="state" required class="form-control input-lg">
        <option value="" selected="selected">select an option</option>
        <option value="ADRAR">ADRAR</option>
        <option value="AIN DEFLA">AIN DEFLA  </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

If you need to insert full text then replace value with option text.